# How to convert string to float number

Tags: go

http://play.golang.org/p/7kR2uZlV5-

This is my playground link.
I have an array of numbers but in string. I tried to convert them to float number but it does not give me anything. What is wrong with it?

```
var numbers []float64

for _, elem := range str_numbers {
    i, err := strconv.ParseFloat(elem, 64)
    if err != nil {
        numbers = append(numbers, i)
    }
}
fmt.Println(numbers)    
    // this gives me nothing  []
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Change

```
if err != nil {
```

to

```
if err == nil {
```

(You may be doing this already, but [unit testing](https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey) is a great way to catch bugs like this.)